# What does super() method do?

Tags: java, class, constructor, super

What does the super method do?

```
public DataFetch(Context context) {
    super();
    this.ctx = context;
}
```

Does this constructor make the context of the newly created object the context of the super class? Not 100% sure how this works. So would the `super()` method essentially just be saying "put me into super class mode" to say it in lay man's terms?

Comment: NB it's not a 'method', it is a way of referring to a constructor in the base class.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It says "initialize my parent class before you initialize me" by calling its default constructor.

Comment: does that essentially mean that the context of the new object is the context of the super class in this case?

Comment: No, the superclass has no direct references to any variables defined in your class. You would have to call a constructor that has a Context argument.

Answer (score 10):

`super()` calls the parent's class constructor (all the way back to Object) and it runs before the current class's constructor.

Comment: Means parent class cannot be abstract class

Comment: @Fennekin An abstract class can have a constructor (which should not be public though). For instance you can define a package private/protected constructor for templating, or even a private constructor (not sure why but it's possible)?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as "superclass context" the context is an interface to access information from the application environment like image resources, system services ect. The context will be from whatever you pass in and is class independent. For instance, an `Activity` is the implementation of the Context interface you are likely to be using and any view you make from within that activity will have the same Context which is actually that provided by the activity.

Answer (score 0):

When used in a constructor, the `super()` keyword appears alone and must be used before the `this` keyword can be used. The `this` keyword may then be used to call functions on a parent object.

Answer (score 0):

The super() is **essential** when the parent class constructor takes any **parameter**

The super() is **not necessary** when the parent class constructor takes **no parameter** because super() will be already specified implicitly.

Look at the code:

```
public class A{  
    int a;
    A(int a){
        this.a=a;
        //Constructor of parent class which requires a parameter
    }   
}  
public class B extends A{
    int b;
    B(int a, int b){
        super(a);
        this.b=b;
        //here super(a) is used to pass the parameter required by the 
        constructor of the parent class A.
    }
}
```

In other words, whenever you create an object for the child class. First, the constructor of the parent class will be called followed by the constructor of the child class. So it is necessary to pass the parameters required by the parent class constructor from the child class constructor using super() method.

Hope it helps!

Please don't forget to **upvote**